# I'd like to create a loop in my filter code

Tags: php, for-loop, text-files

I have a textfile, and in this textfile are domains. I want to delete all the domains that don't have the .com .nl and .be extension. So basically the domains with .org, .de etc. have to go. All the domain extensions are saved in a $key variable. Is it possible to create one loop instead of copy pasting the code and changing the variable?

This works because it is one variable:

```
<?php
$key0 = ".org";

    $fc=file("linklijst.txt");
    $f=fopen("linklijst.txt","w");

    foreach($fc as $line)
    {
        if (!strstr($line,$key0))
            fputs($f,$line);
    }
    fclose($f);
?>
```

But this doesn't:

```
<?php
$keys = array(".org",".de",".fr",".pl",".es",".uk",".jp",".ro",".forum",".us",".in",".it",".co",".ie",".ru",".dk",".tk",".pro",".ml",".gg",".cf",".hu",".kz",".ooo",".ca",".kr",".win",".cz",".ga","se");

$fc=file("linklijst.txt");
$f=fopen("linklijst.txt","w");

foreach($fc as $line)
{
    if (!strstr($line,$keys))
        fputs($f,$line);
}
fclose($f);?>
```

Comment: First of all, copy and pasting code is never a reliable solution if you dont understand the code in the first place. First start learning PHP and then ask a specifc question about a problem.

Comment: _“But this doesn't”_ - of course it doesn’t, `strstr` wants a single value as second parameter, not an array. You will either have to use a second, nested loop, to loop over all keys for each domain - or extract the TLD part (including the dot) from the domain first, so that you can then use `in_array`.

Comment: Btw., your example array does not match what you said you wanted in the description. It contains f.e. both `.com` (which you said you wanted to keep) and `.org` (which you said you wanted to remove.)

Comment: That is a mistake indeed, changed it. @04FS

Comment: I'm not here to discuss. I am here to get answers. Because I really can't get it to work... @CodeSpirit

Comment: just add another foreach in first foreach, to check every value in keys array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your file: domains.txt is like this:

```
example.com
example.net
example.nl
example.de
example.org
example.be
```

You wish to preserve only those with .com, .be and .nl

```
$preserve = ['.com', '.nl', '.be'];
$accepted = []; //will contain the lines we want to preserve.
$lines = file("domains.txt");

foreach($lines as $line) {
    $suffix = substr($line, strrpos($line, ".")); //get the domain suffix
    if (in_array($suffix, $preserve)) {
        $accepted[] = $line;
    }
}

print_r($accepted);
```

This is probably not the most robust code, but I hope it illustrates a decent approach to solving the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I can work my way to the solution with this information :)